# Getting database table column name duplicates in PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

Inside my for each loop to print out column names im getting name duplicates and also numbers for some reason.

```
$q = "SELECT products.name, products.price, products.amount, categories.category_name 
      FROM products 
        LEFT JOIN categories ON (products.category_id = categories.category_id)";

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<th scope='col'>$key</th>";
            }
        } ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

i have 3 products inside my table and I get 3 duplicates of column names

[image]

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php: _“Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, **or both**”_ - you are currently doing the latter, because MYSQLI_BOTH is the default mode.

Comment: I am surprised you are getting anything! As you do not submit that query for execution anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do, I just don't include the code that is not necessary for my question

Comment: `<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {`

Comment: `$i = 1; foreach ($row as $key => $value) { if($i > 1){ continue ;}
            echo "<th scope='col'>$key</th>"; $i++;
            }`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include mysqli_assoc to parameter. But my logic is still not correct as I get duplicates. If I use @devpro code, just getting first column name. There are four of them

Comment: run your loop twice, 1 for heading, and use continue as i mentioned, 2 for your raws. where you will not use continue

Comment: and i dont know why r u using foreach inside your while loop

Comment: @devpro probably wants to output the header then the values, which is sensible.

Comment: @devpro because as i know `mysqli_fetch_array` returns assoc array so I need foreach(). If I remove `while` then where the `$row` will come from?

Comment: @Limpuls have you read the first comment and would you update your code sample? also, why not just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: @devpro putting while loop outside forech is a good idea, i had that before but it didn't work as I wanted so just commented it out. The thing is that it return all the row names `$items = $row['name']` but how can I get column names and not row names? `$items = $row` doesn't work. I use mysqli_fetch_array() with assoc_array return type

Comment: i have shared an example with, where i am using foreach loop twice one for heading and 1 for values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use column name dynamic, then you can store your data into an new array, then you can use this array twice, one for heading and one for values.

```
$newArray = array(); // initiliaze
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // here i am using mysqli_fetch_assoc
    $newArray[] = $row;  // store in a new array
}
```

then, your heading as:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($newArray as $value) {
    if($i > 1) continue; // will use for ist iteration only.
    foreach ($value as $key => $Fvalue) {
        echo "<th scope='col'>".$key."</th>"; // will print headings            
    }   
    $i++;
}
```

then you can show your values as like:

```
foreach ($newArray as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $Fvalue) {
        echo "<td>".$Fvalue."</td>";    // will show all values.                
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I was playing with your code alot, to understand each part. I get it how you use `continue` to print out the headings only once and skip the rest of the loop, but I think you can also use `break` here instead of `continue`, yeah? And I still don't understand why iterations for headings are duplicating multiple times without the `continue`. Why does it act like that, while the loops for values are fine and not repeating?

Comment: continue means, it will not execute any script after continue  @Limpuls